# Traversing a tree: Hibernate LazyFetch dto.getObjects() vs Hibernate.initialize(dto.getObjects)

Tags: java, hibernate

For some reason, when I use `dto.getObjects()` in a session it won't populate the objects but I have to use `Hibernate.initialize(dto.getObjects)`.

Can someone kindly explain to me the reason?

Side question, what is the best way to traverse a tree in as hibernate doesn't have hierarchical query. Some trees has 200 over nodes and 4 levels.

I need to perform a series of update on each node in the tree base on it values and an external variable.

Example:

```
node.setB(node.getA() + abc);
```

any comments? I'm more interested to know the why rather than how.

Answer (score 1):

You should split this into two questions for the best chance at an answer.  With regards to the dto.getObjects() proxy initialization:  merely calling the getter isn't enough, you'll need to call one of the accessor or mutator methods on the collection to have Hibernate initialize the proxy.

The issue here is that when you queried the parent object, Hibernate stepped in and replaced the child collection with a proxy object rather than execute a query for information that you may or may not need.  When you call a method, like size() on the proxied collection, Hibernate knows that you want to actually use the collection, so it runs out to the DB and fetches the data.  If you want to fetch the collection eagerly you'll need to configure the relationship to do so.  There are several ways to do this, we'll need the following information about your setup to best help you:

- Entity configuration (XML vs. Annotations)
- Query mode (Criteria, HQL or calling load()/get())
- Preferably a short code sample of how you're querying

Comment: I did call the accessor. I have a variable private List<Child> children and I called parent.getChildren()

Comment: @seesee: you need to call a method of the returned collection: `parent.getChildren().size()` for example. `parent.getChildren()` just returns the uninitialized lazy collection. The collections initializes itself when you call a method on it. It's the same for a proxy.

Comment: @JB Nizet is there any website that I can read up on this because I saw a lot of publish examples using parent.getChildren() without the Hibernate.Initialize() or .size()

Comment: Most of the tutorials don't use detached objects. The manipulate the entities while the session is open. And Hibernate.initialize() is thus not necessary. Read the javadoc for Hibernate.initialize(), and the official Hibernate documentation.

Comment: Detached Objects? Well I first do a get(id) there after I do a .getChildren().. If I am not wrong the object is still attached and session is open. How do I test? I did read up... that is why I am asking this question. I don't understand why must I user Hibernate.initialize(). Is not  about the answer but I'm trying to understand the process(why).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your follow up question.